# exporting to PDF in a loop in crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am facing difficulties in generating more than 1 PDF's of Crystal report i-e in a loop. Basically I am creating PDF's then zipping those files and generating HTTP Response.For the sake of demonstration of code i am running loop twice here is my code.

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.zip");
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{                    
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            var re = rpt.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            string Name="PDF"+i+".pdf";
            zip.AddEntry(Name, re);
        }
        zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);                          
}

Response.Clear();
```

It successfully generates the zip file but when i try to extract it i gives an error `No archive found (The archive is either in unknown formate or damaged).` Any help would be appreciated. Btw I followed this link [Export Crystal Report to PDF in a Loop only works with first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220649/export-crystal-report-to-pdf-in-a-loop-only-works-with-first)

Answer (score 0):

Using of memorystreem if zip file not attached to local path.

> Response.ClearContent();   Response.ClearHeaders();
>   Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
>   Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;
>   filename=Report.zip");
>
> using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())   {      using (var
>   archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
>   {
>          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
>           {
>               var re = rpt.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
>               string Name="PDF"+i+".pdf";
>               zip.AddEntry(Name, re);
>             zip.Save(memoryStream);
>           }      }   }
>
> memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
>   memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);